# Google Play Games: accessing player profiles from a web browser

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is it possible to access [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en) player profiles from a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A year after your question and the answer was and still is "not yet". They incorporated almost everything onto the cloud but this feature is still waiting its turn.

Comment: Too bad desktop users are often forgotten.

Comment: Almost 7 years after the original post, and we’re still waiting… and forgotten.